# Does Hackage generate haddocks for package candidates?

Tags: haskell, haddock, hackage

I'd like to get feedback on my package's documentation before publishing it to the main index. However, irrespective of how long I wait, Hackage doesn't seem to be building haddocks for my package candidate. Is this a known issue?

Is my only option to release a 0.1.0.0 version of my package and update the versions frequently as a I incorporate feedback from other people?

Comment: I think that was one of the main reasons for candidates. It could be hackage is having issues generating docs

Comment: Is there a status page on hackage somewhere? Or is every package author "operating blind"?

Comment: Relevant comment from last year: https://github.com/haskell/hackage-server/issues/74#issuecomment-873888208

Comment: My impression is that, as of 2022-01-26, Hackage generates documentation for package candidates, including packages that have no published versions. See e.g. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ptera-th-0.1.0.0/candidate, build report: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ptera-th-0.1.0.0/candidate/reports/1

Comment: I was mistaken about the evidence regarding candidates of packages that have no published versions. In the example above, the candidate was surprisingly uploaded _after_ the published version!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether Hackage builds haddocks for package candidates. But there is at least one other option you have: you can build the documentation yourself (e.g. `cabal haddock` will do it and I'm sure stack has something similar) and host it somewhere that the folks you want feedback from can see it -- perhaps even on the Hackage candidate itself.